# Android querying many to many relationships

Tags: java, android, sqlite, database-design

From reading I've understood the way to implement my many-to-many relationship was to have a separate 'Routing Table'. Here's an example of how I've done this:

```
CREATE TABLE Places (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);

CREATE TABLE Tags (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT);

CREATE TABLE RoutingTable_PlacesTags (places_id INTEGER, tag_id INTEGER, FOREIGN KEY(places_id) REFERENCES Places(_id), FOREIGN KEY(tag_id) REFERENCES tags(_id));
```

In my database helper class, I want to have a method that returns a Cursor to all rows in Places that have a particular tag, *Cursor fetchPlaces(int tagID)*. (To allow filtering by tag within the app)

**What would be the correct/best way to go about implementing this?**

I was going to query RoutingTable_PlacesTags, use the returned Cursor to build an array/List of ids for Places, then have another method that I call passing a list/array of id's that returns them all. While I know this would work I'm sure there must be a much cleaner way to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: Think about the cost of doing the query against a normalized schema like the one you have or doing it against a denormalized table and do more work at insert time.

Comment: @Garcon Hi, I was wondering if my answer was satisfactory, and if so, if you were willing to accept it?

Comment: Done, buddy. Apologies for not doing so sooner.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you might mean many to many relationship instead of one to many.

Assuming you do, you can perform the query using one SQL statement:

```
SELECT name
FROM Places
WHERE EXISTS(
SELECT *
FROM RoutingTable_PlacesTags
WHERE RoutingTable_PlacesTags.places_id = Places._id
AND EXISTS (
SELECT *
FROM Tags
WHERE Tags._id = RoutingTable_PlacesTags.tag_id AND Tags.name = 'Searched for tag name here'
))
```